# Deployment of node.js express application in server

Tags: node.js

I have developed one web application using node.js. I used express framework and jade view engine and mysql as a back end. Now i purchased the domain name like XXXXXjewellery.com
when i open this url need to display created application using node.js.
Now in my local machine opening application like localhost:3000 it's openig home page and having menu to navigate other pages. I created application in windows7 operating system.
My app.js file looking like bellow

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var EmployeeProvider = require('./routes/connection').EmployeeProvider;
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

var employeeProvider= new EmployeeProvider();

//Display All Employees
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  employeeProvider.getAllEmployees(function(error, emps){
      res.render('index', {
            title: 'Employees',
            employees:emps
        });
  });
});
//Add New Employee
app.get('/employee/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('employee_new', {
        title: 'New Employee'
    });
});
app.post('/employee/new',function(req,res) {
    employeeProvider.save({
            name: req.param('emp_name'),
            address: req.param('emp_address')
        },function(error,docs) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
});
//update an employee
app.get('/disemployee/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
        employeeProvider.getEmployee(req.param('emp_id'), function(error, resemployee) {
                console.log("Controller Value:");
                console.log(resemployee);
                res.render('employee_edit',
                { 
                        title: 'Edit Employee Details',
                        disemployee: resemployee
                });
        });
});

//save updated employee
app.post('/disemployee/:id/edit', function(req, res) { console.log("EMP ID:"+req.param('emp_id'));
        employeeProvider.update(req.param('emp_id'),{
                name: req.param('name'),
                address: req.param('address')
        }, function(error, docs) {
                res.redirect('/')
        });
});

//delete an employee
app.post('/employee/:id/delete', function(req, res) {
        employeeProvider.delete(req.param('emp_id'), function(error, docs) {
                res.redirect('/')
        });
});
app.get('/getnewsfeed', function (req, res) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ name1: 'sample', name2 : 'sample2'}));
});
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I need to deploy into server and user have to access my application by submitting XXXXJewellers.com url. How to deploy into server.

Comment: This question is too broad. Are you going to deploy to a Windows or to a Linux server? Are you hosting your app in house or through a hosting company?

Comment: Deploying in windows server. Not hosting by company, our self only going to host.

Comment: You probably should look into this then: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx